# Cannot install win32core on Python 3.7 for Windows

Tags: python-3.7, win32gui

I am trying to use some of the Windows user interface functionality of win32core but I cannot get the package installed into python. The installation fails as pep517 trys to build the wheel for win32core.
I have a suspicion that win32core is only for use with cpython.
Is this accurate? 
If so, are there other python packages that allow you to interact with windows?

```
C:\Users\...>pip install win32core
Collecting win32core
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/24/0a/6e0b2e201c76ccd3cda1f97bd64d45daa2b899b50e541962748ec5bc9f5d/win32core-221.28.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: win32core
  Building wheel for win32core (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

 ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for win32core
  Running setup.py clean for win32core
Failed to build win32core
ERROR: Could not build wheels for win32core which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by installing pywin32.